# Checking if a given (remote) git repo has a given commit from a resource constrained system

Tags: git

I'm making a git dashboard federated *thing* and need to look for a given commit on the remote repos. While getting the heads is easy, how do I scan the remote repos for a given commit, considering that I only have 512MB of RAM and 8GB of disk (total) to work with? (less, given the OS requirements and stuff.)

Shallow clones let me get the head commit, but I haven't found a way to shallowly deepen the clone. (i.e. fetch the parent commit(s), then throw away the current commit, then fetch another set of parents, and so on. walk up the commit tree without storing the commit tree or objects at all.)

I know you can deepen a shallow clone, but as far as I can tell that fetches everything starting from the head - including everything you already have.

Comment: I guess you don't have any kind of shell access to the server? Does the server have an API (e.g., if you're using GitHub Enterprise, GitLab, etc.)?

Comment: @Chris too many APIs to write for, not all remote git have an API.

Comment: Oh, so the remotes aren't homogeneous?

Comment: @Chris nope! they can be fairly arbitrary.

Comment: As far as I know all remote commands deal with refs, not commits directly. Is there any guarantee that the given commit will be pointed to by a branch or tag if it exists?

Comment: @Chris it might exist outside branches or tags but I only care about whether it exists in a branch. (I do not care about tags or pull requests.)

Comment: Sorry, to clarify: I don't mean that it's _in_ a branch, I mean that it's at the _tip of_ a branch. I'm guessing not, based on your "shallowly deepen" description.

Comment: @Chris oh. definitely not at the tip.